# Django: INSTALLED_APPS naming conflict?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-settings

I have created custom user authentication in its own app, as the docs recommended. It is named `UserAuth`. However, I also have a `Users` app which handles the various user roles for the project.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'AlmondKing.UserAuth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    'formtools',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'UserAuth.AKUser'
```

This works fine, but when I add `AlmondKing.Users` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`, it breaks:

```
ERRORS:
Users.ManagerAccount.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
Users.CustomerAccount.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
Users.FranchiseAccount.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

The above is printed out when I try to use `runserver`. It is referring to the three models in the `Users` app.

What rule have I broken?

Comment: I guess the problem is in some model where you point to `django.contrib.auth.models.User`

Comment: Ah yes! Wow. I just needed to tell the models to use the new AKUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your models if you are using FK to `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and replace it to point your own Model `UserAuth.AKUser`

Comment: In this case, I'm using a OnetoOneField as I am extending the primary User.

Comment: Consider using to making the FK on `django.conf.settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` so that non-user models don't have to know about which model is used.